# how can i use zhe tar rust package with function append_path

Tags: rust, path, tar

because doc says that

> This function will open the file specified by path and insert the file into the archive as name with appropriate metadata set, returning any I/O error which occurs while writing. The path name for the file inside of this archive will be name is required to be a relative path.

but i want to use another files , here's my code:

```rust
use std::fs;
use serde::Deserialize; // imports both the trait and the derive macro

extern crate tar;

use std::io::prelude::*;
use tar::Builder;
use std::path::PathBuf;


#[derive(Deserialize,Debug)]
struct Config {
    ip: String,
    port: Option<u16>,
    keys: Keys,
}

#[derive(Deserialize,Debug)]
struct Keys {
    github: String,
    travis: Option<String>,
}


fn main() {
    let paths = fs::read_dir("./").unwrap();

    for path in paths {
        println!("Name: {}", path.unwrap().path().display())
    }
    let config_string : String = fs::read_to_string("Config.toml").unwrap();

    let config: Config = toml::from_str(&config_string).unwrap();

    assert_eq!(config.ip, "127.0.0.1");
    assert_eq!(config.port, None);
    assert_eq!(config.keys.github, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    assert_eq!(config.keys.travis.as_ref().unwrap(), "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");

    println!("rect1 is {:#?}", config);

    let file = fs::File::create("source/foo.tar").unwrap();
    let mut a = Builder::new(file);

    let mut path = PathBuf::new();

    path.push(r"E:\");
    // path.push("windows");
    // path.push("system32");
    a.append_path("qbweb_file_wenjian.wenjian").unwrap();
    // a.append_file("b.txt", &mut fs::File::open("c.txt").unwrap()).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: means i cant load files whitch outside the project path when i use  tar packages function :"append_path"